# Deserializing HeaderParam to POJO using Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As part of my rest API I need to access the Operator which is stored encoded in the Authorization header.

I can access this like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Customer post(@RequestBody CustomerRequest request, @RequestHeader(name = "Authorization") String authorization) {
    // Some logic to parse the authorization header here which gets duplicated in every REST method
    Operator operator = parseAuthorization(authorization);
}
```

However this is a bit awkward and requires a lot of duplicate code whenever this is used.

Is there a way I can do this with a custom annotation and some form of middleware like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public Customer post(@RequestBody CustomerRequest request, @Operator Operator operator) {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using Spring Converters e.g.

```
@Component
public class OperatorHeaderConverter implements Converter<String, Operator> {

    private final AuthenticationService service;

    @Autowired
    public OperatorHeaderConverter(AuthenticationService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public Operator convert(String source) {
        return service.parseAuthorization(source);
    }
}
```

Which is configured using:

```
@Configuration
public class ControllerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    private final OperatorHeaderConverter operatorHeaderConverter;

    @Autowired
    public ControllerConfiguration(OperatorHeaderConverter converter) {
        this.operatorHeaderConverter = converter;
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters (FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(operatorHeaderConverter);
    }

}
```

And used in a controller like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public List<CustomerResponse> getCustomers(@RequestHeader(name = "Authorization") Operator operator) {
    // Do something with the operator
}
```

Comment: In every controller method which the operator is used, you have to add a parameter of Operator. If you use an interceptor (add patterns to match related contorller methods), parse Authorization string in the inteceptor, then save the result to a request scope variable or a ThreadLocal variable, you can then get the operator anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter or interceptor to read the authentication header before hitting any controller.

Comment: I need to use the contents of the header in my controller like shown in the example

Answer (score 0):

You can use every class for a header parameter, but you need to configure Spring, so it can convert the String of the header value into that class.
The easiest way to do this is a PropertyEditor.

Implement a class Authorization, with a field for the Operator (add getter if you like)

```
public class Authorization{
  public Operator operator;
}
```

Create a subclass of java.beans.PropertyEditorSupport, that converts the header String into an Authorization

```
public class AuthorizationEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

@Override
public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException{
  //create the Authorization with the Operator here
  Authorization authorization = 
  setValue(authorization)
}

@Override
public String getAsText() {
  //does not matter, is unused here
  return null;
}
}
```

**Important**
Put the class AuthorizationEditor in the same package as the Authorization, Spring will find it automatically there.

Use Authorization as type of the header parameter

```
public Customer post(... @RequestHeader(name = "Authorization") Authorization authorization)
```